# Could not process file <filename>.resx

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resx

I am trying to build a project on visual studio 2019, which has a `<filename>.resx` file.
I get the following error when I build it:

> error MSB3821: Couldn't process file <filename>.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files.

I researched and found that I can unblock the file by right clicking on the file from file explorer and going to properties. But I don't have an unblock option.